# How to I determine the bottleneck for a mapped drive that points to a physical drive on the same server

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

So, I know that if I copy from machine A to machine B it will be slow over a mapped drive. because it's over the network. But I'm sitting in front of a server that is setup with a mapped drive that actually points back to itself. So, technically it should not need to send data over the network.

the arrangement is V: vol1 W: vol2
M: is a mapped drive pointing to W:  So, M: is W:

when I copy from M: --> V: I get 1.2GB/min using robocopy (one point two)

when I copy from W: --> V: I get 45GB/min using robocopy (forty-five)